# Use of Extbase Repositories in Symfony Command

Tags: typo3, extbase, symfony-console, typo3-10.x

Im upgrading an extension to work with TYPO3 v10. Since command controllers can not be used anymore, im migrating them to symfony commands as pointed by the documentation. Everything works smooth as heck except for the usage of extbase repository classes. No matter what i query, i never get a result. Since i can't find any useful information on the web and the documentation i hope this may be just something minor.

After debugging for a while i found out that the pid is not determined correctly while building the query settings. I find that kind of strange since my root template has these lines:

```
plugin.tx_myext.persistence.storagePid = 15403
module.tx_myext.persistence.storagePid = 15403
```

The repository instances are correctly injected by injectMyRepository() methods. I've tried using the extbase ObjectManager to fetch the class instances instead but the "error" stays the same.

Am i doing something wrong or is it not possible to use extbase repository classes in symfony commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After more research i found out that there is some bootstraping missing which results in extension settings (the storageID in my case) not being loaded. From what i've been reading, that behaviour seems intended to prevent extbase booting, i guess?

There is a reference to something similiar in the official documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/CommandControllers/Index.html#initialize-backend-user
Knowing that, i tried to find a method to initialize the missing settings which i could not find. So this does indeed seem like a missing feature.

I developed a workaround which i'm not too proud of, but it's better than nothing (or rebuilding everything to doctrine for that matter). If you stumble upon the same issue, here you go. Just insert and call this method before you fire your query:

```php
public static function initializeConfigurationManager(): void
{
    /** @var ConfigurationManager $configurationManager */
    $configurationManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConfigurationManager::class);
    $tmpConfiguration = $configurationManager->getConfiguration(
        ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK,
        'myExtensionName'
    );

    $configurationManager->setConfiguration($tmpConfiguration);
}
```

That approach exploits the singleton state of the ConfigurationManager. You simply inject the static template of your extension manually and every extbase compound (like repositories) will then use these settings from there on. Lovely.

Be aware however, this is prone to break with future internal changes.